# Replace Assembler memory barrier woth pthreaad code

Tags: memory-management, assembly, pthreads

I have the following code implementing a memory barrier using inline Assembler:

```
 #define barrier() __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")
#define SET_PTR_TO_GLOBALS(x) do { \
    (*(struct globals**)&ptr_to_globals) = (void*)(x); \
    barrier(); \
} while (0)
```

I would lke to replace this with PTHREADS code likw this:

```
  #include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * entry_point(void *arg)
{
#define SET_PTR_TO_GLOBALS(x) do { \
    (*(struct globals**)&ptr_to_globals) = (void*)(x); \
    } while (0)

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    if(pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &entry_point, NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not create thread\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(pthread_join(thr, NULL))
    {
        printf("Could not join thread\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would this replace and preserve the memory barrier functionality provided by the first code block??

Comment: That's not a "memory barrier". That's a "compiler barrier".

Comment: Does that mean that the pthread code will not compile?

Comment: It compiles, but it may be wrong and have subtle, hard to reproduce bugs. You could try running it through a race detector (like tsan or helgrind), but that's not a productive way to write code...

Comment: Your code kind of does not make much sense to me: you create and join a thread that immediately exits (the macro is never used). Are we missing something essential here? There is no apparent connection between your two code sniplets.

Comment: I just publish it as a sample code obviously calling the main() with appropriate parameters will include the macro into the it.